# Problems drawing text onto an ImageView using a Canvas

Tags: java, android, imageview

I'm trying to implement a footer for my ListView which will act as a menu-type frame with five elements. I want the elements to be able to (dynamically, based on user input) display either images or text (or possibly both, but I'm not there yet). Eventually it will be more interactive but for now I was trying to implement it so that the ImageView (which by default displays an image) would erase the image and display text instead.

I thought the best way to implement this was to draw text on a canvas and use the [android.view.View.draw(canvas c)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) method to draw it onto the ImageView. However, I'm having trouble doing this. Specifically, I can modify the view in almost any way (set the background color, change the drawable, etc etc) and it all works fine, and the code to draw the canvas compiles properly, but it doesn't **do** anything at runtime. The view remains completely unchanged.
(**Note:** I've tried to eliminate any stupid mistakes through code (i.e. made sure text wasn't transparent/same color as bg, made sure text was drawn inside the area of the view, etc) but I am not 100% it's error free.)

I tried both drawing to the view passed into the onClick function and drawing to a new ImageView constructed from the passed view - neither works. 
Does anyone have any suggestions? 
Code follows:

```
login_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Bitmap img = Bitmap.createBitmap( 60, 60, Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas();
            c.setBitmap(img);

            Paint myPaint = new Paint();
            myPaint.setTypeface(mFace);
            myPaint.setColor(android.R.color.black);
            myPaint.setTextSize(2);
            myPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);

            String content = "testing";
            c.drawText(content, 0,0, myPaint);
            view.draw(c);//does nothing
            ImageView view2 = (ImageView) view;
            view2.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.white); //this works perfectly
            view2.draw(c);//does nothing
            Toast.makeText(MainListView.this, ""+c.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //making sure c has height - this returns 60 as expected
            Toast.makeText(MainListView.this, "end of method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View.draw(Canvas)` draws the View onto the Canvas, not vice versa like you seem to expect.

If you want to do it along the lines that you already are, you need to extend an existing `View` class, likely `TextView` or `ImageView`, and override `onDraw()`, as explained in the [Custom Components Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).

I think what I would do is use something like a `FrameLayout` and set it to contain either the appropriate `TextView` or `ImageView` as necessary.  That seems cleaner than manually rendering text in an ImageView.

Comment: I just tried the two sequences `view.invalidate();\view.draw(c);` and `view.draw(c);\view.invalidate();` and neither displayed any new behavior. Can you be more specific? If I understand correctly, view.invalidate() should instruct the ui thread that the view is invalid and it needs to redraw the whole thing?

Comment: @matt5784 Sorry, I didn't look closely enough at your code, and the lack of `invalidate()` is what jumped out at me.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the Canvas from the Bitmap, and set the Bitmap as the Image for your ImageView.

```
Bitmap img = Bitmap.createBitmap( 60, 60, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(img);

Paint myPaint = new Paint();
myPaint.setTypeface(mFace);
myPaint.setColor(android.R.color.black);
myPaint.setTextSize(2);
myPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);

String content = "testing";
c.drawText(content, 0,0, myPaint);
ImageView view2 = (ImageView) view;
view2.setImageBitmap(img);
Toast.makeText(MainListView.this, ""+c.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //making sure c has height - this returns 60 as expected
Toast.makeText(MainListView.this, "end of method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Although, I believe the "right" way to do this is to use an extension of View and override the onDraw method to draw differently based on some local variables:

```
login_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((MyView)view).mContextVariable = true; //or false, etc
            //you might not need this invalidate, because the click event probably causes and invalidate to be called
            view.invalidate();
        }
    }

    class MyView extends View
    {
        Paint myPaint;
        boolean mContextVariable;

        public MyView(Context context) 
        {
            super(context);

             myPaint = new Paint();
             myPaint.setTypeface(mFace);
             myPaint.setColor(android.R.color.black);
             myPaint.setTextSize(2);
             myPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            if(mContextVariable)
            {
                //draw something
            }
            else
            {
                //draw something else
            }
            canvas.drawText("testing", 0,0, myPaint);
        }
    }
```