# converting text string to image

Tags: android, image, text, base64

I am converting a text string into an image in my android application. By following various posts on SO, I have written this code.  But it doesn't display the image. 
Is there something wrong with the code?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

     et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);



    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             String text = et.getText().toString();

             byte[] data = null;
            try {
                data = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             final String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bit = StringToBitMap(base64);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bit);

        }

    });

}

 public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
     try{
       byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
       Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
       return bitmap;
     }catch(Exception e){
       e.getMessage();
       return null;
     }
      }
```

Comment: This is not actually converting it to an image. This is converting the bytes that make up a string to base64 and then trying to display them as though they are an image, which as you've found won't work. If you want to get an image out of it I think you need to use canvas/Paint to drawText the String.

Comment: @FoamyGuy thanks.. Could you please explain with some code? I am a first-timer in android

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert the byte[] to an image:

```
Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

There's no reason why you should encode your byte array into Base64 to immediately decode it back.

Although the real question is: what is actually in your EditText? Is it an image converted to a string, or is it just text you're trying to display?

If it's actually an image, then the above will work.

If not, then this is the wrong approach and what it sounds like you need to do, like FoamyGuy said in the comments, is draw the text onto the ImageView's Canvas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10923478/1426565

Although, if you have the text, why not just display it in a TextView and customize the TextView to display everything how you want (ie. font size, color, background, etc)? That would probably be the better approach. If you're unsure of how to use the TextView, check out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: @Cruceo- EditText is actually a plain text. I Actually needed this for converting SMS containing unicode texts (espcially Indian scripts) which are displayed as boxes.

Comment: Try setting the text in the TextView as HTML using the Html.fromHtml() method: mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("your unicode string here")); That should allow you to display characters without the boxes